# iOS Auto layout - injected custom view grow in width according to orientation

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, autolayout

I have a main page view setup. Within this I have a child view which is setup to an outlet. Via this outlet I am injecting a seperate xib file into the page.

What properties can I set on this injected xib so that it grows/shrinks with the device orientation? The child view directly within the main view can grow and shrink but the injected contents of this child view seem to always be a fixed width. How can I make them extend i.e. to cover the red area in landscape?

**N.b.** I am a designer using interface builder to create this. I would appreciate answers that allow me to solve this via interface buidler. If not, then code answers are welcome (only as a last resort).

**See diagram showing the setup:**
[image]

Comment: Do you have autolayout enabled for both xibs?

Comment: Are you using a storyboard or two .xib files?

Comment: im using 2 .xib files and they both have autolayout checked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure I'm correct in thinking that current blueView has no understanding of its superview so you can't set the constraints in the xib itself and will need to do it in code.

To do it with code, presuming redView is an Iboutlet to your red view in the above pictures.

Create your blueView using your nib but make sure that translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints is equal to no:

```
    CustomView *blueView = [CustonView alloc] init]; // or what not
    // atached the xib, should really be done in init of CustomView
    NSArray *subviewArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"myXib" owner:self options:nil];
    UIView *mainView = [subviewArray objectAtIndex:0];
    [blueView addSubview:mainView];


    blueView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.redview addSubview:blueView]
```

Add the constraints:

```
    [self.redView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[blueView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"blueView":blueView}]];
    [self.redView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[blueView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"blueView":blueView}]];
```

Booranger

Answer (score -2):

if the `redView` only has `blueSubView` then you can access it as following

```
UIView *blueView = [redView SubViews]ObjectAtIndex:0];

now you canset the frame of blueSubView.

[blueView setframe:CGRectMake(100,100,100,100)];
```

Hope this will help You.

Comment: can it be achieved via interface builder?

Comment: I think yes..but I am not sure bcoz I usually do everything progarmatically... this is the small code.. u can try it...!

Comment: If you use autolayout concepts such as setting a frame should be avoided.

Comment: @Andrea correct I am using auto layout, I am trying to avoid setting specific 'origins' or 'dimensions' if possible - it seems as though this answer is going against the descriptive concept of auto layout

Comment: @DaveHaigh I don't think this could be done using IB, or at least not in the last version of xcode. For what I uderstood you want the view size changes accordind to its superview. This can be done using autolayout by adding constraints, the response of BooRanger seems the most correct.